# Track write requests on Read-only database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, read-only-database

I have changed one of the databases to read-only in SQL Server 2005. I would like to track if someone tries to write to the database.

Any suggestions on how to track such requests (end user write request failures)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A readonly database is "READ_ONLY". No writes are allowed - the application will get an error stating that the database is readonly.

You can run a server side trace (since you are stuck with sql server 2005) and look for `user error messages` and filter your database by ID.

Comment: Thanks Kin. I would like to keep the database in read-only mode for few weeks. Running trace may not be a viable option. Is there any way (ex: Trace Flag) so I can trace it in error logs? My intention is to find if any application is trying to change the data in this database.

Comment: @Vijred I dont think any trace flag can record this and using Trace flag for things like this is not a good idea. I would suggest you to look into server side trace - [check this out that I use for server migrations](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheRockStarDBA/31d781b0fae1de40d0aa/raw/b72c4d25fc7399b64ccc4491f176357c0ba0fc4c/Profiler%2520Trace%2520-%2520sa%2520and%2520logins.sql). This will tell you what applications/hostnames are connecting to your database. You can adjust the script as per your needs.